# Echoing an environment variable based on another variable

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have an environment variable called `test1` whose value is `test_value`. How can I display `test_value` by using another variable `$target='test1'`?

Here are what I've tried:

```
$target='test1'
echo $env:$target    
echo $env:$($target) 
echo "$env:$target"
```

All of the 3 methods above fail to display `test_value`. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$env:test1 = 'test_value'
$target = 'test1'
$value = Invoke-Expression ('$env:' + $target)
$value
```